# Matlab 2021 silent installation

Tags: powershell, matlab

I have a problem installing Matlab 2021b silently on windows using packer and powershell.
This part also print out installation error: Exit code: 0 which is ok
Script part that is problematic:

```
Write-Host "Starting MATLAB installation"
# Run the MATLAB installer with the input file
Write-Host "Running MATLAB installer. This might take some time..."

if (Test-Path -Path $installer_input_path) {
    Write-Host "Found the installer input file at $installer_input_path"
} else {
    Write-Host "Did not find the installer input file at $installer_input_path"
    throw "MATLAB installer input file not found"
}

try {
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath ".\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "-inputFile $installer_input_path" -NoNewWindow -PassThru

    Write-Host "Exit code: $($process.ExitCode)"
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error executing setup: $_"
}

# Copy the license file to the MATLAB licenses directory
$matlab_license_dir = Join-Path $env:MATLAB_ROOT "licenses\license.lic"
Copy-Item -Path $license_file_path -Destination $matlab_license_dir

Write-Host "MATLAB installation complete"
```

Give me error:

```
      azure-arm: Starting MATLAB installation
      azure-arm: Running MATLAB installer. This might take some time...
      azure-arm: Found the installer input file at C:\TEMP\scripts\installers\matlab_installer_input.txt
      azure-arm: Exit code: 0
  ==> azure-arm: Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Tools\MATLAB\R2021b\licenses\license.lic'.
  ==> azure-arm: At C:\TEMP\scripts\installers\Install-Matlab.ps1:74 char:1
  ==> azure-arm: + Copy-Item -Path $license_file_path -Destination $matlab_license_dir
  ==> azure-arm: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ==> azure-arm:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
  ==> azure-arm:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
  ==> azure-arm:
  ==> azure-arm: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
  ==> azure-arm:
```

Comment: Where did you get these instructions? The error is pretty clear. The `Join-Path` command fails because the `license.lic` file is not in the `licenses` folder

Comment: The environmental variable MATLAB_ROOT is not set properly.